# Getting the current location only after the second time startUpdatingLocation is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

```
{
...
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

        NSLog(@"myLocation1: %@",[locations lastObject]);
        myLocation = [locations lastObject];
        NSLog(@"myLocation2: %@",[locations lastObject]);
        [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

        [self doSomethingWithLocation];    
}
```

Currently I'm in the location 40.000,40.000.
I'm closing my app and change location to 10.000,10.000

When entering the app again and running `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` my log will show:

```
myLocation1: <+40.00000000,+40.00000000>
myLocation2: <+40.00000000,+40.00000000>
```

If I'll trigger `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` again my log will show:

```
myLocation1: <+10.00000000,+10.00000000>
myLocation2: <+10.00000000,+10.00000000>
```

How can I call `didUpdateLocations` once and still get the current location?
Should I use another delegate?

I guess I could place `stopUpdatingLocation` inside `doSomethingWithLocation` and run `doSomethingWithLocation` after some sort of delay in order for the right location to be updated but I'm sure that's not the way it's meant to be.

Thanks

Comment: Are you tried to read the location from the CLLocationManager instead of locations array ?

Comment: Yes. `[locationManager location]` will always show the same values and won't even update after the second call to `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leave the location manager running for a while (e.g. 30 seconds), setting a timer to tell it to stop. The location manager updates are like pancakes, the first one you get isn't always the best.

Answer (score 1):

The first update you are seeing is likely a "stale" location, which was determined many minutes ago when location services were last powered up. Or it may be a very inaccurate location determined using cell-tower positioning, for example. If you just need to get the device's current location, using Core Location directly requires a good deal of code because you must handle these cases. (The CLLocationManager API appears to be built for apps that need continuous location updates, like turn-by-turn GPS navigation apps.)

Instead of using CLLocationManager directly, I suggest you take a look at using an [open source component such as INTULocationManager](https://github.com/intuit/LocationManager) which will handle all of this work for you and make it trivially simple to request one or more discrete requests for the device's current location.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should check timestamp of location. User does not move on such distances so quickly.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

        CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
        if(fabs([location.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow]) < 5)//seconds
        {
            myLocation = location;
            manager.delegate = nil;
            [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
            [self doSomethingWithLocation];
        }
}
```